How are files handled in Swift programs?
I've learned a bit of Python: enough to build a simple calendaring command line app. However, I'm new to Swift programming, and a big sticking point is my unfamiliarity of using Xcode. How are files handled in Xcode? Do we use relative paths with some variable, like how Windows has %WINDIR%? I know that apps are typically distributed in special folders called bundles, but I need some kind of primer on the environment from a coding point of view. Reading this, you can tell I'm confused.
To make this less vague, consider the following code in a command line project in Xcode:
let Holidays: [String: (String?, Bool)] = [
    "New Year's Day": ("art/NewYearsDay.png", true),
    "Martin Luther King Jr. Day": ("art/MLKDay.png", true),
    "2023-02-14": ("art/ValentinesDay.png", false),
    "Labor Day": ("art/LaborDay.png", true),
    "2023-10-31": ("art/Halloween.png", false),
    "Thanksgiving": ("art/Thanksgiving.png", true),
    "Christmas Day": ("art/ChristmasDay.png", true)
]

I don't know how to define these specific files. I've tried dragging them into the Xcode project, but I'm not sure how I'm supposed to proceed to make the code correct in terms of pointing to them.
Consider the next example:
let filePath = "./output.pdf"

I understand that in Python, this would indicate a file relative to the location of the main.py file. However, in Swift, in the Mac OS environment, I've never seen an example of how to point to a file correctly in an Xcode project. I'm just having a little trouble, since on Mac OS, these things are typically obscured so much that I don't have any reference points for what is correct.
I appreciate anyone willing to give context or point me in the right direction.

This is an interesting question, because "dynamic" languages like Python, Ruby and JS work substantially differently than "compiled" languages like Swift, Java, C, etc.
When using CPython, the interpreter executes your main Python file, which then requests for the interpreter to load other files. This all happens at runtime, and there is no notion of "compile" time. The location of these files matters, because the interpreter needs to find the first one, and the relative references to the other source files needs to be correct.
More conventionally compiled languages (like Swift) are quite different. All the relevant files are read by the Swift compiler when you build the program. They can live anywhere on your system, and that doesn't have any impact on the behaviour of the resulting executable.
How to locate/load files depends on whether you're talking about files related to your application (e.g. assets like storyboards, icons, 3d models etc.), or user files (e.g. user preferences, documents, etc.)
For application files
These are files that you want to bundle with your application, to be available for your program to load at runtime. You typically manage them with Asset Catalogs in Xcode. Their exact location isn't something you should worry about, instead you ask the Bundle APIs to find them for you, e.g.
guard let pdfLocation = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Example", withExtension: "pdf") else {
    fatalError("Could not find Example.pdf in this app's bundle")
}

// Avoid `Data(contentsOf:)`, because it will block the thread
// to wait for the load, but it's good for a simple example like this
let fileContent = Data(contentsOf: pdfLocation)

For user files
These are files that don't bundle with your application, but are created/edited by it.
How file paths work depends on which API you're using. Most commonly, relative paths are relative to the "current working directory". That's usually more relevant for command line utilities and not graphical apps, but it's still worth mentioning.
FileManager is the main API for interacting with the file system. It has a bunch of functions for writing/reading files by absolute or relative URLs, etc.
Macs have many different places to place files, depending on the purpose, e.g. Downloads, Documents, Preferences, etc. FileManager and URL both add helpers for generating the correct paths for various needs, without hard-coding them. E.g. for a file in the user's downloads folder, you might use:
let fm = FileManager.default
let fileURL = fm
    .url(for: .downloadsDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
    .appendingPathComponent("some/folder/abc.txt")
print(fileURL) // => "file:///Users/Alex/Downloads/some/folder/abc.txt"


I don't think Bundle.main.url(forResource:) would work out of the box in a command line app though? Command line apps don't have a bundle by default as far as I know.

@Sweeper Yeah, CLI tools are an exception. there does happen to be a way to inject data segments into a mach-o executable, but Bundler can’t be used to read those.
